# Are YouTube and Google+ API activities the same thing?

Tags: youtube-api, google-plus

I want to get the `activityId` of a YouTube video with the v3 API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/activities?part=id&channelId=UCMm8XFMnB2wODJqYt6d6OJQ&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

and using that `activityId`, get the comments with the Google+ API:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/activityId/comments
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not the same but they are getting closer and closer to being the same. The switch to using [Google+ comments on YouTube](http://youtube-global.blogspot.com/2013/09/youtube-new-comments.html) is a good example. Keep in mind though that there are subtle differences too, like YouTube comments are all visible to anyone who can see the video but the new G+ comments have very fine grained permission levels.

Comment: Thank You, abraham. So I couldn't access to Youtube activities from Google Plus API, could I?

Comment: No. You can only access Google+ activities from the G+ API where some of the activities will also happen to be YouTube activities.